# eureka-js-client module overwrites "hostName" while running on AWS

Tags: node.js, node-modules, netflix-eureka

I am using eureka-js-client to register on Eureka, this works fine when deployed locally, however when I deploy on the AWS, the "hostName" value set is replaced with empty value.

Since I set ingressUrl as hostName, how to stop eureka-js-client not to touch the "hostName" ?

eureka-js-client version - "4.2.0"
Eureka version - 1.9.2, (SpringBoot 2.x)

Here's portion of Eureka config looks like:

```java
"instance": {
    "app": "<MyApp>",
    "hostName": "<MyHostname>", // I dont want this to be overwritten by AWS-meta-data
    "ipAddr": "<MyIp>",
    "vipAddress": "<MyVip>",
    "secureVipAddress": "<address>",
    "homePageUrl": "<url>",
    "healthCheckUrl": "<url>",
    "statusPageUrl": "<url>",
    "instanceId": "<InstanceId>"
    "port": {
      "$": 80,
      "@enabled": false
    },
    "securePort": {
      "$": 443,
      "@enabled": true
    },
    "dataCenterInfo": {
      "@class": "com.netflix.appinfo.AmazonInfo",
      "name": "Amazon"
    },
  },
  "useLocalMetadata": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I end up doing,

```
"instance": {
    "app": "<MyApp>",
    "hostName": "<MyHostname>", // I dont want this to be overwritten by AWS-meta-data
    "ipAddr": "<MyIp>",
    "vipAddress": "<MyVip>",
    "secureVipAddress": "<address>",
    "homePageUrl": "<url>",
    "healthCheckUrl": "<url>",
    "statusPageUrl": "<url>",
    "instanceId": "<InstanceId>"
    "port": {
      "$": 80,
      "@enabled": false
    },
    "securePort": {
      "$": 443,
      "@enabled": true
    },
    "dataCenterInfo": {
      "@class": "com.netflix.appinfo.AmazonInfo",
      "name": "Amazon"
    },
    "eureka": {
       "serviceUrls": {
          "default": "<eureka_url>"
        },
       "fetchMetadata" : false, #turn this off, and set your own metadata, you can use AWSmetada.js present in eurek-client-js
       "registerWithEureka" : true
    }
}
```

for more details see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/eureka-js-client#configuring-for-aws-environments